# How can I restart app one time - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-lifecycle

I have to update data on firebase database. After I need restart my app ONE TIME. How can I do that ?

```
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                        .child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).child("country")
                        .setValue(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                        .child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).child("city")
                        .setValue(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                        .child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).child("ilce")
                        .setValue(addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea());
```

Comment: What do you mean through restart? And why do you need that?

Comment: If I change data, adapter can't refreshed. WhenI  restart app works perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried to notify the adapter regarding the changes?

Comment: Yes I tried but not working

Comment: Please add the code that you have used to notify the adapter.

Comment: When add this code, app restart constantly

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to restart an app just to get new data from Realtime Database.  You should adjust the internal state of your app as needed.  You can even set up a listener on the locations that may change in order to receive updates as soon as they happen.

Comment: How can I do that ? I added this code     " adapter.startListening();"       But not working :(

Comment: Use the documentation to understand how Realtime Database listeners work for reading data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I know this documentation but I couldn't apply to my code